# Angular JS Material Design: one mdDialog, multiple templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, material-design, angular-material

Im trying to build a dynamic dialog that shows different content depending on what the user clicks. This means erasing/hiding everything shown on the dialog and showing something new. I could just write all of the html in one template and hide/show it but...Is there a way to render different templates inside that dialog template? Just so I can have different templates for whats shown inside the dialog and just have a router of some sort to render these templates inside the same dialog. Is this possible?

```
<md-dialog>
   <md-dialog-content ng-controller="someCtrl">
       <a href="/screen1">Go to screen 1! </a>
       <a href="/screen2">Go to screen 2!</a>

       <ng-view/>
       <!-- Show here the chosen template -->

   </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include the ngRoute module, and the script tag linking to it.

You'll have a div like this.

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

You'll have a partialRoutes.js file looking something like this.

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: './partials/things.html'
    })
    .when('/stuff',{
        templateUrl: './partials/stuff.html'
    })
    .when('/otherstuff',{
        templateUrl: './partials/otherstuff.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
    })
});
```

When you include ngRoute it will look something like this.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Here are the docs for ngRoute. Hope I helped.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Thanks! Decided to take a different approach at the end, using ng-switch to switch the divs in and out of view, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  I thought I had to use the locals option, but I got it working without that, since I'm dealing with a string and not a javascript object.

I had a requirement to add a second dialog to our application and I used an if/else block to pass the url string in.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.displayDialog = function (ev) {
            var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement; //Second OR condition for IE.
            var id = target.id

            if(id === 'dialogId'){
                templateUrlValue = 'templateA.html';
            }else{
                templateUrlValue = 'templateB.html';
            }

            $scope.dialog = true;
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'dialogCtrl',
                templateUrl: templateUrlValue,
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: true
            }).then(function (answer) {
                }, function () {
                });
        };
```

Which allows me to choose which dialog to open by it's id.